# force mocha to not skip some of the time

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

In mocha, I have a couple unit tests which use `skip`

```
it.skip('login (return photo)', function(done) { ...
```

However, in some cases, I want to force not skipping, like before a deployment. Is there a flag I can pass mocha to do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.skip` is provided as a way to omit a test without having to comment it out, potentially forgetting about it forever. You're probably better off conditionally registering the test yourself.

Perhaps something like this:

```
var isDev = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development';

describe('stuff', function() {
  if (!isDev) {
    it('login (return photo)', function (done) { ... }
  }
});
```